# Why does this cause a browser lock(infinite loop I presume)

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this statement hanging?

```
while ((matched = rx.exec(text)) != null) {
  while((m = rx.exec(matched[0])) != null) {

  }
}
```

Comment: If you go back and look at your question, do any questions pop out at you? Like, for instance: **What's `rx`?** And **What's `text`?** ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing the actual values of text and rx and what actually happens in this loop depends upon the content of those, but one theory is that the `.exec()` method with the "g" flag maintains state from one call to the next precisely so that you can call it repeatedly in a single loop.  For your outer loop to work properly, that state must be preserved from one iteration of the outer loop to the next.

But, when you take that same regex object and use it to search something different in the inner loop, that state is not going to be preserved properly - the outer state in the `rx` object is going to be disturbed by the inner loop which is also using the same `rx` object.

Your double loop would probably work if you used separate regex objects for each loop like this:

```
while ((matched = rx1.exec(text)) != null) {
  while((m = rx2.exec(matched[0])) != null) {

  }
}
```

They would need to be truly separate regex objects, not references to the same regex object.

In addition, `matched[0]` contains the whole match from the outer search so you've just matched `matched[0]` in the outer loop with your regex and then you ask to match again on the exact same thing you just matched with the same regex.  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?  It doesn't seem like the inner loop would do anything useful.

As with many questions here on SO, if you back up and tell us what you're really trying to accomplish, we could probably provide more useful info towards actually solving your real problem.

In any case, my first three paragraphs explain why this could easily be an infinite loop.

Comment: Your theory is absolutely correct; the regex stores state, so switching between target strings with a single regex results in weird behavior.  See the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: I was thinking that might be the issue with the states. I'm working on a syntax active highlighter and I needed the syntax to highlight within certain other syntax's e.g. <a href=""> </a>, as of now I just have a single while(... != null) and it only grabs the <a ...> </a> for coloring. I needed to search within to grab the "" if the rules existed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeDepies - Without seeing the actual regex and the actual data you're searching, all I can recommend is that you MUST have separate regex objects for the two loops.  Without that, you will get an infinite loop most if not all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I've figured it out. atleast in theory.

Answer (score 1):

`matched[0]` always contains the whole match, so the inner loop might never terminate.

Comment: The inner loop will terminate just fine.  Repeated calls to `exec()` will advance through all possible matches until no more matches and then return null.  It's the outer loop that won't terminate.  See my answer for a description of why.

Comment: I should add that the inner loop will terminate if the regex has the "g" flag on it.